# How to calculate sum taking account conditions?

Tags: excel

I want to make a calculation based on two conditions. if I have a table

```
   teacher  student          score    

 1. john      David              5
 2. john      Carlos             5
 3. john      David              3
 4. sam       David              2
 5. sam       Diana              3
 6. sam       Diana              4 
 7. josh      carlos             3
 8. josh      David              2
```

I want to sum the values of

so basically i want to sum student score that is repeated  within a range of rows of specific teachers. If the name is repeated with a different teacher, that is not added if another teacher has the same student. , lets say, David is repeated within teacher john two times so I add those two and sam also has David score as well but not add it to John since he is a different teacher

... is there a way to do a calculation like this in excel? Perhaps produce a table like this?

```
    teacher  student          score  

 1. john      David              8
 2. john      Carlos             5
 3. sam       David              2
 4. sam       Diana              7
 5. josh      carlos             3
 6. josh      David              2
```

Comment: There is a feature called 'pivot'. You can use that.

Comment: read docs about sumif Excel function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Pivot

- select Data
- Click on Insert → Pivot Table
- Select Fields in Pivot properties box

[image: Excel Pivot]

---

### Using Sub totals

- Select your data
- Go to Data → Sub Totals
- Select "At Each change in Column2"
- Use function 'Sum'
- Add subtotal to 'Column1' & 'Count'

[image: Excel Sub totals]

Comment: Thanks!! helped a lot

Comment: @franco3131,Good to hear that !. As the answer helped to resolve the question, you can [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking check mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Raju says - use a Pivot Table.

Starting with this data ...

[image]

Select the Insert Ribbon and Pivot Table. Put Teacher and Student in Rows, and Score in Values ...

[image]

There's a lot of flexibility in how you layout your report.